# get std_msgs::Header associated with a frame from image_transport?

Tags: ros, std-msgs, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to get the std::msgs::Header associated with an image sent over image_transport?  I need some unique key from my images to stick in the header of mesages derived from them to maintain the association.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218134/get-std_msgs::header-associated-with-a-frame-from-image_transport?/) by [drewm1980](https://answers.ros.org/users/1742/drewm1980/) on ROS Answers with karma: 258 on 2015-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The images are passed as `sensor_msgs::Image` messages. You can definitely access the contents of the header in those messages. The header contains seq, stamp and frame_id. If for example you have a callback `imageCb`, then you can follow the code snippet to access the contents of the header.

```
   void imageCb(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg){  
          std::cout << msg->header.seq <<  std::endl;
          std::cout << msg->header.stamp <<  std::endl;
          std::cout << msg->header.frame_id <<  std::endl;
   }
```

Is this what you want?

---

Originally posted by [Willson Amalraj](https://answers.ros.org/users/5060/willson-amalraj/) with karma: 206 on 2015-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [drewm1980](https://answers.ros.org/users/1742/drewm1980/) on 2015-10-20**:
Yes, thanks!